# Setting the 'Make endpoints public' app settings via .lu file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

We are looking at creating a LUIS conversation app using the 'bf luis:build' 'bf luis:convert' etc CLI.

We have .lu files that we convert to JSON, use the CLI to create the LUIS conversation app.

The .lu file seems to allow for setting various settings like the following.

```
 !# @app.luis_schema_version = 7.0.0
> !# @app.settings.NormalizePunctuation = true
> !# @app.settings.NormalizeWordForm = true
> !# @app.tokenizerVersion = 1.0.0
```

But we could not find any documentation on an app setting related to the 'Make endpoints public' setting.

Anyone aware of how to set that setting using an .lu file 'directive'.  I came across REST API way of doing it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-luis/authoringv2.0/apps/update-settings.  But, looking for using the .lu file for accomplishing the same.

Thank you

Regards

-Athadu

[image: LUIS App settings]

Answer (score 1):

Please raise an issue in the following [link](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues) for the additional settings.

.lu file format is introduced to present a typical language model in a conversation context that can perform two common tasks, intent classification and entity extraction.

Customization via LU parser

The parsing interface in LU parser has been updated to accept one more parameter, a config (a set of feature flags) which enables or disables certain optional features.

For example, in Orchestrator and PVA’s case, the config should be

{   enablePattern: false,

enableMLEntities: false,

enableListEntities: false,

enableCompositeEntities: false,

enablePrebuiltEntities: false,

enableRegexEntities: false,

enablePhraseLists: false

}

See more examples [here] (https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/pull/992/files#diff-f290f989ea67db4d9a497c1599e5d5cd)